# bash: trouble to assign an regex extracted substring to a variable

Tags: bash

It shall be simple, but I couldn't solve it...
I'm trying to extract the last part of a path and assign it to a variable

```
Base=/home/user2/SetOne
Set="$(expr "$Base" : '([^\/]+$)')"
```

and expect to end up with "SetOne" in $Set.

Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) is here to help you:

```
$ Base=/home/user2/SetOne
$ Set="${Base##*/}"
$ echo $Set
SetOne
```

The `"${Base##*/}"` means:

Using the variable `Base`, remove the longest matching (`##`) pattern which is everything before slash (`*/`)

Comment: Thanks a lot  Itération 122442 ! It works well for me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand, what you are trying to achieve, but the regex in `expr` is a **basic** regular expression. Therefore, the + is taken literally, and since there is no `+` in your string, you don't get a match.

Even seen as a extended regex, your regex is odd. `[^\/]+` describes one or more of the characters `^`, `\`  or `/`, and since `expr` implicitly anchors the regex at the beginning of the string, and you explicitly anchor it with `$` at the end, it means that your extended regexp would matche only if `Base` is not empty and consists just of those characters.

But let's assume that this is really what you want to do. For extended regex matching, don't use `expr`, but the bash `=~` operator:

```
# Matches if Base consists only of the characters ^ \ /
[[ $Base =~ ^([^\/]+$) ]]
((Set=1-$?)) # Sets Set to 1 on a match and 0 on a non-match.
```

I have added a caret in front of the regex, to mimic the behaviour of `expr`: While `expr` implicitly anchors the regex at the start of the string, `=~` does not do this.

Note the calculation of `Set`: `expr` writes to stdout `1` on a match and `0` on a non-match, while the status code of `[[ ... ]]` is the opposite; so I guess this is what you want to achieve, and the `1-$?` does exactly this inverting.

Of course we could also have inverted the condition, and then just take the status code, i.e.

```
! [[ $Base =~ ^([^\/]+$) ]]
Set=$?
```

Of course with your example string, you would also get a non-match with my solution, but this is simply because the string in `Base` contains unwanted characters.